# how do i calculate the average in console application using c#

Tags: c#, average

this is developing code its a basic application i need help with code to work out the average the average is supposed to equal and display 3.00

```
    // Define constrants and variables
    // Constrants
    int MAX_RESPONSE = 5;
    int MIN_RESPONSE = 1;
    int MAX_QUESTIONS = 50;
    string scale5 = "5 - STRONGLY AGREE";
    string scale4 = "4 - AGREE";
    string scale3 = "3 - NEITHER AGREE NOT DISAGREE";
    string scale2 = "2 - DISAGREE";
    string scale1 = "1 - STRONGLY DISAGREE";
    string scale0 = "0 - UNABLE TO ANSWER";
    string Question = "Question : C# is better than C++. Do you\n";

        // Variables
        int Response = 0;
        int ValidResponseCount = 5;
        int NonResponseCount = 2;
        int QuestionCount = 7;
        int MaximumResponse = MIN_RESPONSE;
        int MinimumResponse = MAX_RESPONSE;
        int TotalResponse = 1;
        var AverageResponse = 0;

        //calculate
        AverageResponse = TotalResponse / ValidResponseCount;


        // Output results
        Console.WriteLine("SURVEY RECORDING SYSTEM ");
        Console.WriteLine(Question + "\n" +
            "\t" + scale5 + "\n" +
            "\t" + scale4 + "\n" +
            "\t" + scale3 + "\n" +
            "\t" + scale2 + "\n" +
            "\t" + scale1 + "\n" +
            "\t" + scale0 + "\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("response value");
        Console.WriteLine("RESULTS " +
            "\n Number of valid responses     : " + ValidResponseCount +
            "\n Number of non responses       : " + NonResponseCount +
            "\n Number of times question asked: " + QuestionCount +
            "\n Maximum response              : " + MaximumResponse +
            "\n Minimum response              : " + MinimumResponse +
            "\n Average response value        : " + AverageResponse);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double AverageResponse = (double)TotalResponse / (double)ValidResponseCount;
```

Would do - since you're using Integers, `/` will return you an integer and probably round up/down the result, casting to `double` will change this result to a valid one